# Not working in some browser like chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, viewport

The mobile phone view does not show the menu and also chrome for smart phone .this the link to the test environment.[link](http://testmail.haoyetu.com/)
this my header.php

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
        <title>WandaSoko</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/favicon/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>

        <!--systling start here -->
                        <!--bootstrap -->
        <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
        <!--link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"-->
                        <!--custom-->
        <link href="assets/css/wandasoko.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" /> 
                        <!-- Custom Fonts -->
        <link href="assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
                        <!--out sourced custom font-->
                        <!--other css_-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/swipebox.css">
                        <!--slider flow controller-->
        <link href="assets/css/slider_flow.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />

        <!--link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,700,300,100' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'-->
        <!--link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'-->
    </head>
<body>
```

Comment: @ – Paulie_D dont anawer a question  if you dont have answer .your comment does not help

Comment: I haven't answered the question. I merely pointed our the deficiencies in your question.

Comment: Then you fail to understand how Stack Overflow works. Users **are** here to judge your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'<meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/favicon/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
```

'

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `@media queries`

I just had a look at your page source code. You dont even have any js for the navbar. It appears as though you are using just css to resize the navbar.

So i recommend you look at implementing a responsive bootstrap navbar. Then you use media queries for it to change on viewport change, you then need to add this line in your `<head>` - `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` but this will only work once you have got the css and js for the navbar.

I will not do it for you, but googling for a bootstrap navbar is a start?

Comment: My js is on a separate  file .the above  code is only  for header.php. the js is on a file called  footer.php